# As a newbie in rule-based reasoning,how can I have a basic knowledge of the Resoning component of Apache Jena?

Tags: jena, rules, reasoning, jena-rules

just like how Jena works in reasoning?or some relevant papers in rule-based reasoning?Thank U very much.

Answer (score 0):

[Reasoners and rule engines: Jena inference support](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/index.html)